# Select photo from camera and show crop option with fixed size android

Tags: android

my requirement is to crop image with fixed size in android.. I am getting image from gallery or camera  and now want to show fixed size of crop option on that image so that user just drag the rectangle box and set anywhere on the image and save.

Answer (score 0):

Please google your question before asking them on StackOverflow...

There are plenty of libraries which are doing what you want. I use [this one](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) which is stable, clear and easy to use but you'll find plenty of others just by looking on Github with a search [like this](https://github.com/search?q=crop%20android&ref=opensearch).

For the fixed size, there is maybe an option directly implemented in the API of the library I proposed you (never had this requirement), but if not, you just have to change the draw method of the transparent rectangle.